# MySQL Install trouble Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: mysql, mac, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I have tried installing versions 5.5.11 and 5.1.56 of the MySQL Community Server DMG on my new MacBook Pro 2GHz Intel Core i7 running OS X 10.6.6.

It claims that installation is successful, and the Preference Pane window claims that the server is running, but I can't run 'mysql' commands in the Terminal, nor does any MySQL related process show in the Activity Monitor. Can anyone help?

I tried the answer given here, but still no action.

Mysql wont start on Mac OSX?

Thanks in advance, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Add MySQL's bin folder to the path (e.g. in `.bash_profile`):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the Activity Monitor is filtering for 'All Processes', 'mysqld' will be displayed, otherwise your Pref Pane woudln't show it.
2. Type this at your console, to link the mysql client to your /usr/bin

> sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/bin/mysql

Good location for downloads:

> http://mirror.services.wisc.edu/mysql/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/